# Date format in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have a column (date) in csv which stores the date in "2003-02-01"(y-m-d). I would like to format the date in month and year like Apr 2003. how do i do that?

```
var format = d3.time.format("%m-%Y");
data.forEach(function(d,i) {
d.date = format(d.date);
});
```

I am getting the following error Error: `TypeError: n.getFullYear is not a function Line: 5`

the csv file contains values:

```
200,300,400,288,123,2003-01-01
300,700,600,388,500,2003-02-01
```

what is the issue here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Javascript doesn't automatically recognize the values in the CSV file as dates, just reading them in as strings. [d3's time functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) make it pretty easy to convert them to [datetime objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
> parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse
> parseDate('2003-01-01')
Wed Jan 01 2003 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

To format the dates like you want, we need to go the other way, from a date object to a string:

```
> formatDate = d3.time.format("%b-%Y")
> formatDate(parseDate('2003-01-01'))
"Jan-2003"
```

I would recommend representing your dates within your program with date objects and only formatting them as strings when you need to display them.

Comment: var format = d3.time.format("%b-%Y");
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
data.forEach(function(d,i) {
d.date = format(parseDate(d.date));
}); I am still getting the error.

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format 
The format seems to have been updated to
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%B %d, %Y");
parseTime("June 30, 2015");

Answer (score 6):

D3 version 4 has different time methods now.

https://keithpblog.org/post/upgrading-d3-from-v3-to-v4/
https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Your source date

```
var d = {created_time : "2018-01-15T12:37:30+0000"}
```

The structure of that date = %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z

*I search google with "2018-01-15T12:37:30+0000" and it's suggestions provided the date structure string. Handy.*

Create a timeParser to convert(parse) your date string into a date object

```
var parseDate = d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
//parseDate(d.created_time)
```

Now create a time formatter to return a formated date string for displaying.

```
var formatDate = d3.timeFormat("%b-%Y")
return formatDate(parseDate(d.created_time))
```

i.e. 
Jan-1970

Comment: because i kept getting it wrong on so many levels, and then tried to fix, each time worse than the time before. I think its better now though. :-p

Answer (score 2):

from Adam answer, here is a small helper function to convert a time string from a format to another:

```
var formatTime = function(input, formatInput, formatOutput){
    var dateParse = d3.time.format(formatInput).parse;
    var dateFormat = d3.time.format(formatOutput);
    return dateFormat(dateParse(input));
};
```

use:

```
formatTime("2003-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d", "%b-%Y");

// output -> "Jan-2003"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting date lets say in variable " d = (e.g: '2003-03-01')" in string format then,

```
var monthNameFormat = d3.time.format("%b-%Y");
return monthNameFormat(new Date(d));
```

this will result date in "**Jan-2003**" format.

Answer (score 1):

In D3Js v3, this worked for me:

```
var s = "2018-11-01T19:37:55Z";

d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").parse(s);

// Thu Nov 01 2018 19:37:55 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```