# How to convert date for my D3 line graph

Tags: javascript, json, date, d3.js

I have a graph from D3.js the JSON data that is returned is around 400 values of

[{"date":"/Date(1471356000000)/","val":97.2346},{"date":"/Date(1471354200000)/","val":98.1901}......}]

I want to convert the date to the format as shown in the D3 example 
In my case I have to have the time as the value changes with half hour increments in time(X axis has time in the date)

I tried [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569) and was able to convert the Date

```
new Date(parseInt(result[1].date.substr(6)));
```

**Output: Tue Aug 16 2016 08:30:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)**

How do I convert it to the format which D3 understands?

Comment: Have you look at this library http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/ca0adb7e426c12c06a95 it lets you look at your formated time in d3.time.format specifiers.

Comment: I tried this new Date(parseInt(result[1].date.substr(6))).d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y%H:%M");

Comment: Not sure if thats the way to do it?

Comment: Try sticking on a to you varaible `.toLocaleDateString();`

Comment: It does not return the Time. OUTPUT:"8/16/2016"

Comment: @JNewton—terrible idea, *toLocaleDateString* is entirely implementation dependent and produces different results in different browsers and different regional settings.

Comment: Maybe you're after an answer like [*Date format in D3.js*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721929/date-format-in-d3-js).

Comment: this did convert the date with time on it but the graph still is unable to plot